# How to read a text file in ancient encoding?

Tags: character-encoding

There is a public project called Moby containing several word lists. Some files contain European alphabets symbols and were created in pre-Unicode time. Readme, dated 1993, reads:

> "Foreign words commonly used in English usually include their
>   diacritical marks, for example, the acute accent e is denoted by ASCII
>   142."

Wikipedia says that the last ASCII symbol has number 127.

For example this file: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3203/files/mobypos.txt contains symbols that I couldn't read in any of vatious Latin encodings. (There are plenty of such symbols in the very end of section of words beginning with B, just before C letter. )

Could someone advise please what encoding should be used for reading this file or how can it be converted to some readable modern encoding?

Comment: ASCII codes run higher than 127; they actually run to 255. It's called [extended ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com). Any software or library capable of reading ASCII text can read the file; whether or not they get displayed properly will depend on how you're trying to display them, and you've provided no details of how you're planning on using the files.

Comment: I want to convert it to UTF-8 for machine text processing. (BTW, the link about extended ASCII says that character 142 is rather diacritical Z, than diacritical e. Maybe this is the reason why modern editors including browsers don't read this file?)

Comment: What :"modern editors" are you referring to? MS Word, Notepad, and Notepad++ all read the extended ASCII character set perfectly well. The link I posted shows you the definition of the character set, not what your editor might display, which I also mentioned in my prior comment. You still have not explained how you are "reading" the file or how you're attempting to display it, and you've not defined "modern editor"; you've not even indicated what platform you're using.  Can you possibly be more vague here?

Comment: The link also tells you that it's ISO 8859-1, which tells you which encoding you should use.

Comment: "ancient encodings" that made me feel old.

Comment: bche\N bte noire\h btise\N are these words displayed OK in your browser? Or more specifically those words in the file that I described in the post?

Comment: probably those words came from files with different and mismatched encodings. sometimes encoding errors like those are irreversible, but some words are identifiable. for example B‰tard-Montrachet\N seems to be Bâtard-Montrachet.

Comment: @1010 - In other words, those words were copy-pasted from files with different encodings? Hmm.. Can "academic" and "public" language project published on Guttenberg project site can contain words with lost encoding information? Here the page about that file: http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html

Comment: @AlBerger well, we were just seeing it with the wrong encoding. matt's answer explains the ‰/â mismatch too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little research suggests that the encoding for this page is [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman), which has `é` at position 142. Viewing the page you linked and changing the encoding (in Chrome, View → Encoding → Western (Macintosh)) seems  to display all the words correctly (it is incorrectly reporting ISO-8859-1).

How you deal with this depends on the language / tools you are using. Here’s an example of how you could convert into UTF-8 with Ruby:

```ruby
require 'open-uri'

s = open('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3203/files/mobypos.txt').read
s.force_encoding('macroman')
s.encode!('utf-8')
```

You are right in that ASCII only goes up to position 127 (it’s a 7-bit encoding), but there are a large number of 8 bit encodings that are supersets of ASCII and people sometimes refer to those as [“Extended ASCII”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). It appears that whoever wrote the readme you refer to didn’t know about the variety of encodings and thought the one he happened to be using at the time was universal.

There isn’t a general solution to problems like this, as there is no guaranteed way to determine the encoding of some text from the text itself. In this case I just used Wikipedia to look through a few until I found one that matched. Joel Spolsky’s article [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a good place to start reading about character sets and encodings if you want to learn more.